# Circle clip path

Tags: html, css

I have a circular image. I want to cut the top of it as I have shown in the picture. Is it possible to do this with clip path?

Thanks.

[image]

```css
.circle {
  width: 75px;
  height: 75px;
  background-color: red;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="circle">

</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you could use the [`inset()` CSS function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/basic-shape/inset) :

```css
.circle {
  width: 75px;
  height: 75px;
  background-color: red;
  border-radius: 50%;
  clip-path: inset(20px 0 0 0);
}
```

```html
<div class="circle">

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

mask can also do it:

```css
.circle {
  width: 75px;
  height: 75px;
  background-color: red;
  border-radius: 50%;
  -webkit-mask: linear-gradient(#0000 20%,#000 0);
}
```

```html
<div class="circle">

</div>
```